# Week-wise data from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the count of records from a table week-wise by setting first day of week as Saturday.

My query is :

```
SET DATEFIRST 6

SELECT     
    DATEPART(MONTH, GeneratedAt) AS 'Month',  
    DATEPART(WEEK, GeneratedAt) - DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GeneratedAt), 0)) + 1 AS 'Week',
    COUNT(*) AS 'Visits'  
FROM
    MyTable  
WHERE
    DATEPART(Month, GeneratedAt) = DATEPART(Month, GETDATE())   
GROUP BY  
    DATEPART(WEEK, GeneratedAt) - DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GeneratedAt), 0)) + 1,
    DATEPART(MONTH, GeneratedAt)
ORDER BY     
    'Month',  
    'Week'
```

Result:

```
Month   Week    Visits
-----------------------
11      2       21
11      3       34
11      4       22
11      5       22
11      6       7
```

Sample data of `MyTable`:

```
Id  GeneratedAt
----------------------------
123 2019-11-02 15:03:07.117
124 2019-11-02 15:03:42.040
125 2019-11-02 15:03:56.887
126 2019-11-03 11:53:47.720
127 2019-11-03 11:58:59.333
128 2019-11-03 12:02:26.480
129 2019-11-03 12:04:06.550
130 2019-11-03 14:26:02.547
131 2019-11-05 12:42:48.307
132 2019-11-05 12:43:13.437
133 2019-11-05 12:43:24.787
134 2019-11-05 12:43:50.030
135 2019-11-05 15:35:47.057
136 2019-11-05 16:33:39.057
137 2019-11-05 16:38:40.717
138 2019-11-06 12:58:49.807
139 2019-11-06 12:59:02.367
140 2019-11-07 10:59:47.350
```

The issue I am facing is I need fixed week numbers even if it is zero. As per the sample data week 1 should display 0 visits.

Expected output:

```
 Month  Week    Visits
 -----------------------
    11      1       0  
    11      2       21
    11      3       34
    11      4       22
    11      5       22
    11      6       7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the query as:

```
with CTE as
(
SELECT     
          DATEPART(MONTH, GeneratedAt) AS 'Month',  
          DATEPART(WEEK, GeneratedAt)- 
          DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM,0,GeneratedAt), 0))+ 1 
          AS 'Week',
          COUNT(*) AS 'Visits'  
FROM     MyTable  
where DATEPART(Month, GeneratedAt)=DATEPART(Month, GETDATE())   
GROUP BY  
          DATEPART(WEEK, GeneratedAt)-
          DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM,0,GeneratedAt), 0))+ 1 ,
          DATEPART(MONTH, GeneratedAt)
)
select isnull(CTE.[Month],DATEPART(Month, GETDATE())) as [Month],
      AllWeek.wk as [Week],
      isnull (CTE.[Visits],0) as Visits
from CTE
right join (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) as AllWeek(wk) 
on AllWeek.wk = CTE.[Week]
ORDER BY     
[Month],[Week]
```

[Sample code here..](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=12c176d1eec4762aeeb155b31458d8f6)

Comment: Week 1 should give 0 visits.When we consider Nov 2019 with Sat as start day, we will get 6 weeks. 1st Nov in week 1, 2nd to 8th Nov in week 2 etc. So as per sample data Week1 should give 0 visits .

Comment: Yes it will...please check the sample code I have shared..hope that helps!!

Comment: What does DATEPART(Month, GETDATE()-2)  in 

FROM     MyTable  
where DATEPART(Month, GeneratedAt)=DATEPART(Month, GETDATE()-2)

Comment: Today is 2nd December 2019..to get the data in sync with your posted data ..I have substraced two days from current date..:)